# Not able to upload image even with 10 reputation

Tags: support, status-norepro, reputation, new-users, images

I am not able to upload image even with 10 reputation, is there anything else I should do?

It is saying

> You need at least 10 reputation to post images.

[image: Error Message Screenshot]

Comment: Are you trying to upload an image to a stack exchange site other than the one you have 10 rep on?

Comment: Nope, I am in the same site and I can see 10 reputation in the top, still I see this error

Comment: I would normally suggest that it's a caching issue somewhere, but more than 6 hours since you reached 10rep seems quite long.

Comment: Try logging out then logging in again.

Comment: Pretty sure it doesn't count the first, i.e. you really need 11 (to have gained 10)

Comment: @staticbeast If so, then message should read "you need more than 10 rep to post images" (or "at least 11") ...

Comment: Try getting above 10, not equal to 10.

Comment: This could be related to the recent DC move, I believe they're still working out some neck pain from that.