# Privilege wiki of "Remove new user restrictions" promises too much

Tags: discussion, new-users, privileges-page

After reading [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167426) I took a look at the "Remove new user restrictions" privilege wiki page. The [current version (Revision 10)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/66524/10) of this page is misleading somehow in my opinion.

**Access to review queues in general**

At the top the privilege wiki states that the user now has access to the review tools, while stating at the bottom that this feature remains hidden until the user reaches a 125 reputation points:

> Review allows you to monitor posts that are likely to require additional assistance from more experienced users. It is thus geared towards users with more than 125 reputation who have a better grasp of the site and its policy than a user with 10 reputation might have; **the feature is, indeed, completely hidden until then**.

(Emphasis by me)

This is inconsistent in my opinion. Can users with 10 reputation points access the `/review` pages or not?

**Access to low quality review queue in special**

Furthermore the wiki page indicates that users should look at the low quality posts review queue to find posts that most likely can be improved:

> This privilege level unlocks it, though, and you can help through editing. Look at [low quality posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts) and see if you can propose improvements to them.

Can users with 10 reputation points access the `/review/low-quality-posts` queue anywhere on  the StackExchange network? On StackOverflow and here on Meta this is not possible, so that paragraph should possible be altered.

NB: I did not propose a change to that wiki, because I know that the privilige wikis are maintained here on Meta and published to every other site on the network and I was not sure whether I understood the privilege wiki correctly - though that may be an indicator that it needs some clarification ;).

Comment: It probably has not been updated. The content about review is added in 2011.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [full revision history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/66524/revisions), you will see that the paragraph about review is added on Nov 11th, 2011, way before the current review queue is implemented. I have just removed the paragraph (but it is weird that it takes effect instantly even though I haven't got 20k rep on meta?).

<s>By the way, it seems that First Post and Late Answers queue are **not** mentioned in [Edit questions and answers wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit). I guess it also requires 2k rep, but I would leave the editing job to someone who can confirm it.</s>

Comment: Thanks for improving the wiki page!

Answer (score 1):

The sentence you highlighted ("the feature is, indeed, completely hidden until then") simply means the link users with a reputation higher than 124 would see is not visible to users with a reputation equal to 10. They can access the page by manually entering the URL.

As for the Low Quality Posts queue being accessible to users with a reputation equal to 10, that is not exact: It is accessible to 2K users.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: `They can access the page by manually entering the URL.` Even an anon can access if they know the link. `Low Quality Posts queue being accessible to users with a reputation equal to 10` I think it was accessible to 10 rep user in the old system, it is still visible to <2k user a while ago, but now it is completely hidden to <2k.

Comment: Can a user with 10 reputation points access any of the queues? Because he can do nothing of the required review actions. He cannot flag, and he cannot downvote and he cannot comment. So maybe the "review"-part should be hidden from that privilege wiki altogether?

Comment: @Spontifixus: Since user at any rep and even anon can suggest edit (still true now), the review queue is open to 10 rep user in the past. Currently, under the new review system, it is only visible to 2k user, since reviewing requires more experience.

Comment: @nhahtdh Even an anonymous user can suggest an edit - that's not the question here. The question is whether the privilege page should suggest that the user has access to review queues when that is not the case...

Comment: @Spontifixus: As I have posted, I have removed the paragraph about the review queue in 10 rep - since it no longer applies.

Comment: @Spontifixus 15 rep users can enter the community eval reviews, and I think the firstposts or something

Comment: @BenBrocka: Isn't that on the beta site only?

Comment: @nhahtdh they ran on most sites just recently, UX had one. I think the huge sites like SO skipped it though